# Discretization of a heat equation using finite-difference method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

Let $\overline{\Omega}=\left([0,2]\times [0,1]\right)\cup \left([1,2]\times [1,2]\right)$ and $\Gamma=\Gamma_1\cup\ldots\cup\Gamma_6$ be defined as shown in the following picture:

[image: 1]

I want to discretize the following heat equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-D\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right) &= 0, \text{ for all }(x,y)\in\Omega\\
D\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}n_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}n_2\right) &= 0, \text{ for all }(x,y)\in\Gamma_2\cup\Gamma_3\cup\Gamma_5\cup\Gamma_6\\
u &= u_0, \text{ in }\Gamma_1\\
u &= u_1, \text{ in }\Gamma_4
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $h$ is the step width of the used lattice and $D,u_0,u_1$ are given constants. I want to find a matrix $K_h$ and a vector $b_h$ such that $K_hu_h=b_h$, where $u_h$ is the approximate solution vector.

If $(x_i,y_j)$ is a point on the lattice and $u_{ij}=u(x_i,y_j)$, I want to use the approximations $$\Delta u_{ij}=\nabla^2u_{ij}\approx\frac{1}{h^2}\left(u_{i+1,j}+u_{i-1,j}-4u_{ij}+u_{i,j+1}+u_{i,j-1}\right)$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_{ij}\approx\frac{u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}}{2h}$$ as well as $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u_{ij}\approx\frac{u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}}{2h}$$

---

Suppose we first consider $\Omega_1=(0,1)\times (0,1)$. We construct our grid $G^{(h)}$ by the tensor product of two grids of $(0,1)$: $$G_x^{(h)}:=\left\{x_i=(i-1)h:1\le i\le N\right\}\text{   and   }G_y^{(h)}:=\left\{y_j=(i-1)h:1\le j\le N\right\}$$ where N:=\frac{h+1}{h}. Using our approximations, we've got the following equations:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
D\frac{1}{h^2}\left(4u_{ij}-u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j}-u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}\right)&=0\text{ , for all }1\le i,j\le N\\
-D\frac{u_{i,2}-u_{i,0}}{2h}&=0\text{ , for all } 0\le i\le N+1\\
D\frac{u_{i,N+1}-u_{i,N-1}}{2h}&=0\text{ , for all } 0\le i\le N+1\\
u_{1j}&=u_1\text{ , for all } 1\le j\le N
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Please note that I've split the second equations for the half of $\Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_6$. There some problems left: First of all, $u_{i,0}$ and $u_{i,N+1}$ are not well-defined. We can use the first equation for $j=1$ and $j=N$ in combination with the second and third equation, respectively. Insertion and scaling by a factor of $1/2$ yields $$D\frac{1}{h^2}\left(2u_{i,1}-\frac12 u_{i+1,1}-\frac12 u_{i-1,1}-u_{i,2}\right)=0$$ and $$D\frac{1}{h^2}\left(2u_{iN}-\frac12 u_{i+1,N}-\frac12 u_{i-1,N}-u_{i,N-1}\right)=0$$ Now there are still problems with the corner nodes $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and (maybe?) $(1,1)$.

For $(0,0)$ we consider $(i,j)=(0,0)$ and there are 3 equations involved: From the first equation we've got $$4u_{1,1}-u_{2,1}-u_{0,1}-u_{1,2}-u_{1,0}=0\tag{1}$$ From the second equation we've got: $$u_{1,2}-u_{1,0}=0\tag{2}$$ and the third equations yields $$u_{1,1}=u_1\tag{3}$$ However, we've got now information about $u_{0,1}$.

So there are three questions left:

1. What can we say about $u_{0,1}$?
2. How do we describe all these equations on $\Omega_1$ in a linear equation system "$Ax=b$"
3. Suppose we've got all linear three linear equation systems for $\Omega_1$ as well as $\Omega_2=(1,2)\times (0,1)$ and $\Omega_3=(1,2)\times (1,2)$. How do we combine these systems into one system for $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a rectangular lattice on $[0,1]^2$ and on $[1,2] \times [0,2]$ separately. Merge them (in the process making the lattice points on $\{ 1 \} \times [0,1]$ only count once, of course). The awkward thing in this circumstance is that the "ghost points" have to be defined in a rather asymmetric fashion.

Comment: @oxbadfood That depends on the data structure which is convenient for your application. If you're just writing down a matrix equation, then you'll need to reindex. One convenient way to do this might be to actually split the problem into $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, $[1,2] \times [0,1]$, $[1,2] \times [1,2]$. Then you have three square lattices with exactly the same number of mesh points (modulo the ghost point problem), which makes designing a reindexing scheme not very difficult.

Comment: @oxbadfood A lazy approach would be to extend your lattice to the whole square $[0,2]^2$ (or actually, $[-h,2+h]^2$, because of the Neumann conditions on the left, bottom, and right). Then you write your equations for the interior by going across rows of the lattice, with equations for the exterior nodes being simply $u_{i,j} = 0$. Just be careful not to do this for the points which are not "truly" outside the domain, i.e. your Neumann BC ghost points. Also be sure to use a sparse matrix structure if you do this, because otherwise it will be more than twice as slow as it has to be.

Comment: Please note: I've made an edit on my question. I hope the problems I've got are now somehow clearer formulated.

Comment: @oxbadfood You can deal with the boundary by using ghost points. You extend the DE to the boundary of your domain proper, so at for example $u_{i,0}$ you have $u_{i,0} = \text{average}(u_{i,-1},u_{i,1},u_{i+1,0},u_{i-1,0})$. Then you formally insert points such as this $u_{i,-1}$ to use for the Neumann boundary condition. That is, the normal derivative at $u_{i,0}$ is proportional to $u_{i,1}-u_{i,-1}$, and similar elsewhere. I forget what exactly you have to do in order to manage the corners (or any other point where analytically speaking the outward normal is not defined).

Comment: As for writing everything in a linear system, you have to perform some sort of interlacing in order to turn your 2D array $\{ u_{i,j} \}_{i=1,j=1}^{i=N_x,j=N_y}$ into a 1D array. Then you just write down each equation after reindexing using this interlacing scheme.

Comment: As for *combining* the linear systems, again you have to "re-interlace" and match the overlapping points.

Comment: Can you suggest any reading about this topic? Especially about how to deal with a region like $\Omega$ which is not a rectangle.

Comment: @oxbadfood Not really, because the only difference from the case of the rectangle is designing an indexing scheme. I think most people tend to make these schemes themselves, because it is fairly intuitive how you would design them. In particular, you can do the following. Make $N_x$ and $N_y$ both odd. (So $h=2/(m-1)$ for an odd integer $m$.) Take the first $N_x N_y/4$ points (rounding down) by going across rows in the top square (not counting its lower boundary). Then take $N_x N_y/2$ points (rounding up) by again going across rows in the lower rectangle (counting its upper boundary).

Comment: @oxbadfood One thing I will say is that *in general* the boundary of the domain is in your scheme. In the Dirichlet case it participates in the trivial equation that it is equal, and contributes to its neighbors via the Laplacian in the interior. In the Neumann case it contributes to its neighbors via the Laplacian in the interior and also has its own Laplacian, which references the value of the ghost point(s), which is determined by the boundary condition(s).

Comment: As an example, $u_{2,1} = \text{average}(u_{1,1},u_{3,1},u_{2,0},u_{2,2})$. The $u_{2,0}$ here is formally $\text{average}(u_{1,0},u_{3,0},u_{2,-1},u_{2,1})$, and the Neumann BC implies that $u_{2,-1}$ should be *defined* as $u_{2,1}$. In this way every point has an equation (either its Dirichlet condition, a Laplacian condition, or for the ghost points a Neumann condition). The only problem is at the corners, where you have to arbitrarily choose which direction should be the outward normal. On a fine enough mesh this effect is quite small.

Comment: What I meant: How *exactly* should I deal with the corner point $u_{0,1}$?

Comment: @oxbadfood If both of the intersecting sides were Dirichlet, the solution would be more or less obvious, except if the two conditions did not agree, in which case you would to define the problem weakly. If both of the intersecting sides were Neumann, I would consider $u_{0,0}$ to be part of the domain. Its equation would wind up being $u_{0,0} = 2 u_{1,0} + 2 u_{0,1}$, by applying both BCs simultaneously. Because you have an intersection of a Dirichlet and a Neumann side, I think the easiest thing to do is to call the corner part of the Dirichlet side, which gives $u_{0,0} = u_1$.

Comment: @oxbadfood Note that this means I misspoke earlier, because I thought the BCs at the corner $u_{0,0}$ were both Neumann. They *are* both Neumann at the other corner, however.

Comment: Let's conclude what we've got: The given problem has no *solution*. Instead, there are multiple ways to deal with the *Neumann-conditions* and some of them are rather tricky or at least discussable?.

Comment: @oxbadfood Except at the corners, everything is OK. On $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_4$ you have Dirichlet conditions, which are easy to handle. On the rest of the boundary, you have Neumann conditions, which you deal with by using a centered difference at the boundary which reaches into the interior and out to a ghost point. This defines the value of the ghost point, which allows you to consider the discrete Laplacian at the Neumann boundary point. We have the example $u_{2,0} = u_{2,-1}+u_{2,1}+u_{1,0}+u_{3,0} = 2 u_{2,1} + u_{1,0} + u_{3,0}$ since the Neumann condition gives $u_{2,-1} = u_{2,1}$.

Comment: @oxbadfood At the corners, from the finite difference point of view you have an ambiguity, because it is not entirely clear which boundary segment a corner is on. If it is on two Neumann segments, which outward normal do you use? If it is on a Dirichlet segment and a Neumann segment, which *type* of condition do you use? This problem vanishes entirely if you develop your scheme as a discretization of the integral which arises when you weakly formulate the original problem, the same way that finite element methods are derived.

Comment: Let me ask a last question: Does the parameter $D$ make any sense at all? Moreover, I think we can forget about the whole factor $\frac{D}{h^2}$ when constructing the coefficient matrix.

Comment: @oxbadfood $D$ is the diffusion coefficient here. If you had a nontrivial Neumann condition, a mixed condition, or evolution in time, then you would need to include it. As it stands it can be divided out (or more precisely nondimensionalized out).